# React + Next.Js server action function for rendering components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, next.js, server

Lets say i have a parent component **ChatingWindowsWrapper**. I would like to pass to this components some props. One of properties is **renderFn** which should be executed inside wrapper component and render child components. Here is code:

```
          <ChatingWindowsWrapper renderItemsProps={[
        {
          window_slug:"artificium",
          window_icon: artificium_icon,
          window_name:"Artificium"
        },
        {
          window_slug:"artificium",
          window_icon: artificium_icon,
          window_name:"Artificium"
        },
        {
          window_slug:"artificium",
          window_icon: artificium_icon,
          window_name:"Artificium"
        }
      ]}
      renderFn={
        async (item, isClicked) => {
          'use server'
          return <ChattingWindow window_slug={item.window_slug} window_icon={item.window_icon} window_name={item.window_name} isClicked={isClicked}/>
        } 
      }
      />
```

And inside of this component:

```
const ChatingWindowsWrapper = ({renderItemsProps, renderFn}:Props) => {
    const [ mounted, setIsMounted ] = useState<boolean>(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsMounted(true)
    },[])
    return mounted ?
        <div className='chatting_windows_icons font-plus_jakarta_sans flex gap-10'>
            {
                renderItemsProps.map(async (item, index) => await renderFn(item, true))
            }
        </div>        
    :null
}

export default ChatingWindowsWrapper
```

My question now is why renderFn not render JSX.Element as it should? I was expecting that this function will render three ChattingWindow components?

I will mention that im useing here t use server directive inside renderFN to mark this function as server action which is required by next in order to avoid errors.

Thanks !